# Write Chinese Characters And Alphabet in Cells Into .CSV

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv, utf, cjk

I'm trying to write data into a CSV file. The data contains both Chinese Characters and general text. My results look like this after exporting it into CSV file:

[image]

But it is supposed to look like this:

[image]

All the Chinese Characters, like "物料申请系统", "ADC培训", etc. are all turned into "?".

Here is my code:

```
Open Location For Output As #1
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            If j = LastCol Then 'keep writing to same line
                TextLine = TextLine & Cells(i, j).Text  'read line into variable
            Else 'end the line
                TextLine = TextLine & Cells(i, j).Text & Deliminator
            End If
        Next j
            Print #1, TextLine
            TextLine = ""
    Next i
Close #1
```

Comment: Are you aware that there are two kinds of Chinese characters? Some have a Unicode representation, and others (the more rare ones) only exist as drawings, which makes them impossible to put in a flat textfiles (like a CSV), regardless of the encoding.

Comment: I'm not aware of that, but assuming this is Unicode, how should I do it?

Comment: How did you examine the text file?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Do you mean how do I open the .csv file? If yes, I use either notepad++ or Microsoft excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 your_worksheet.SaveAs "your file path and name", xlUnicodeText
```

You could also use the `FileSystemObject`

I don't believe the VBA `Open for Output : Print (or Write)` support Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was able to generate the text without any problem. Cheers :D

Comment: Consider it Done :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ron Rosenfeld for suggesting **FileSystemObject**. I was able to generate the CSV file with both Chinese Characters and general text without any problem with the following code that I amended:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  With .CreateTextFile(Location, , True)
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            If j = LastCol Then
                TextLine = TextLine & Cells(i, j).Text
            Else
                TextLine = TextLine & Cells(i, j).Text & Deliminator
            End If
        Next j
            .WriteLine TextLine
            TextLine = ""
    Next i
        .Close
  End With
End With
```